# How to delete password in vim without storing it in a register?

Tags: vim, passwords, vi, wipe

I have a password in a text file. I'm editing the file in vim and I want to delete the password. If I just delete it, say with 'dw', it's stored in several registers. I want to avoid keeping any track of the password in vim.

The closest I managed to get is to use the black hole register: '"_dw' - this doesn't store the password in the usual registers, but it still remains in the '".' register.

Comment: Why not press the delete button repeatedly?

Comment: Niffle: are you kidding me? From the website: "Vim is a highly configurable text editor built to enable efficient text editing." What if I have a whole file of paswords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black hole register is the way to go. 
The "last inserted text register" `".` contains the password only if it was the last text entered. Have in mind that the password although deleted still exists in the undo history. I would recommend the following:

```
:let old_undolevels = &undolevels
:set undolevels=-1                   
:exe "normal a \<BS>\<Esc>"
:let &undolevels = old_undolevels
:unlet old_undolevels
```

That will clear the undo history and the `".` register.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete something else into the black hole register, which would wipe out the previous contents, or you could directly assign something to it like this:

```
:let @_=""
```

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing - '"_dwddu'. Nothing faster so far.